# What do I do with my idol collection?

Tags: punch-quest

I have been collecting idols during my runs through the cave, and I just discovered that the list of acquired idols can be viewed on the stats page. There are also different colors (bronze, silver, and gold), which I assume refer to the quality of the idol.

Do these idols have any effect on gameplay? Are they used for anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't seem to do anything I have over a thousand of the buggers now. I want to collect them all due to my completist attitude but they 
Have made no difference at all apart from the pure gold ones you need for an achievement and in all 900 games I have played I only have 3 so far